# Software doesn't close even if server connection is disconnected on Windows XP only

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, windows-server-2008

We develop software which will be installed in a server PC and it will be used by other users in their client PC. When we update our software we need to close all the client connection to the server which uses the software. By using `openfiles` we disconnect all open files related to that software.

When we disconnect those open files, the client PC user gets a message like "stopped working" and software closes as it cannot work without connection to the server (this is what we would like to happen). It works this way on both Windows 7 and Windows 8.

But for all clients on Windows XP, no error message shows when the connection is disconnected and the software continues running. Because of this, the software gives so many errors due to the loss of connectivity. The connections will only reestablish if the user closes and reopens the software manually.

What could cause this? As I mentioned it works fine on later versions of Windows, but not Windows XP.